# How to uncheck checkboxes using Typescript and Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a group of check boxes all with a class 'types'. I have a button on the page that should select and unselect all checkboxes in the group

Checking the boxes works like this:

```
$('.types').attr('checked', 'true');
```

Unchecking the boxes like this doesn't work:

```
$('.types').attr('checked', 'false');
```

Unchecking the boxes like this throws an error:

```
$('.types').attr('checked', false);
```

Error: Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type '(index: number, attr: string) => string | number'

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: try with `.prop("checked",false)`

Comment: This $(".types").attr('checked',"true") is working for me
https://plnkr.co/edit/yrmcqooUKjVZeTPb5pE0?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newer versions of JQuery, you need to use this.

```
$('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
$('.types').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: It's good practice to add some explanation of what the code does (or why it works). This is to the benefit of the OP as well as others finding this answer afterwards.